# How can I create a replication slot without hanging when using logical replication on AWS RDS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, logical-replication

I am trying to build replica using logical replication on our production environment.
We have selected list of tables from each schema for this process. The source and target machines are AWS RDS instances and version 11.7

The statement to create publication works perfectly.

When trying to create replication slot, the process hangs and waits for other queries to complete.

```
CREATE PUBLICATION prod1_pub FOR TABLE schema1.table1,
schema1.table2,
schema1.table3
schema1.table4
schema1.table5;

SELECT pg_create_logical_replication_slot('prod_pglogical_rep01', 'pgoutput');
```

`LOG:  process 13573 still waiting for ShareLock on transaction 285346403 after 1000.110 ms DETAIL:  Process holding the lock: 30902. Wait queue: 13573.`
Is there a way to create the slot avoiding this problem?

Comment: Sure, stop 30902 doing whatever it is doing.  It would probably be best to figure out what that is....

Comment: Yeah tried that , But as soon as I terminate/cancel the session that's blocking new ones starts to interrupt.

Comment: OK. But what is it doing?  Look in pg_stat_activity.  Maybe you can prevent that whole class of thing from happening.